# Why was my question put on hold?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about whatsapp: [Is there an option to remove the "administrative" messages from a whatsapp chat?](https://superuser.com/questions/1211332/is-there-an-option-to-remove-the-administrative-messages-from-a-whatsapp-chat) and it wos put on hold because:

> "This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center."

Why is the question off topic, while the other [whatsapp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp) questions are on topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WhatsApp is a mobile and web-only application. Questions regarding those are off-topic here. They would be better suited to [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) or the dedicated mobile platform Stack Exchange ([Android](https://android.stackexchange.com) or [Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com)).

Answer (score 3):

And a quite a lot of them are closed - whatsapp is *primarily* a webapp and a mobile app, which happens to have a somewhat odd desktop application.

I suppose *we* can do better by having a tag wiki entry reflecting what sort of whatsapp questions would be on topic here (dealing with the desktop version mainly).

From the screenshot, it looks like the mobile app, which is off topic. Even if it wasn't the current question isn't answerable without the platform its running on.